# Custom JavaScript not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajaxaddtocart

I'm trying to call my custom **JavaScript** function in **addtocart.phtml** file, but it's not working.

After user clicked **add to cart** button, I'm calling my custom **JavaScript** function using , but not woring. For this, I tried below code.

Added below code to `addtocart.phtml` file from **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view**

```
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            },
            "ABCSolutions_CustomModule/js/custom": {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
```

And Custom Js file

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($,customerData) {
    "use strict";    
    //creating jquery widget
    $.widget('mage.custom', {
        _create: function() {

            //bind click event of elem id
            this.element.on('click', function(e){
                console.log('Click ME!');
                console.log(customerData.get('customer'));
            });
        }

    });

    return $.mage.custom;
});
```

I tried both **category** and **product** page it's not working. Could you please suggest us to work above code for both pages after **add to cart** button clicked.

Comment: Did you create requirejs-config.js?

Comment: @RohanHapani, No. In My Custom module having `custom.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create requirejs-config.js file in your view/frontend folder to set path of your custom js file and paste the below code :

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'mage/custom': 'ABCSolutions_CustomModule/js/custom'
    }
};
```

### UPDATE :

For catalog page :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
"[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
    "ABCSolutions_CustomModule/js/custom": {

    }
}
```

And then, change code in your js based on page.

Then, upgrade and deploy your module :

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Hope, it will helpful for you.

Comment: Here what is `mage/custom`?

Comment: You added mage.custom in your js file. So, you need to write mage/custom in your requirejs-config file to set alias of ABCSolutions_CustomModule/js/custom js file.

Comment: Okay, let's try.

Comment: It's working on the product page only. How to work with this in category list page also?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Now, It's working or not?

Comment: Thank you, now it's working fine.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom js in the phtml file then you need to add like this way:

1) require-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'yourCustomJs': 'ABCSolutions_CustomModule/js/custom'
    }
};
```

2) addtocart.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {

        require(['jquery','yourCustomJs',],
        function($){ 
             jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    window.obj.init();
             }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
```

3) yourCustomJs.js

```
window.obj = {
     init: function() {
          // Your Custom Js code.
     });
};
```

Try this, it will help you.
(Note:  If you want to check this then just print one alert or console message then check it. So, you can make sure that this is properly working.)

Answer (score 0):

Please try as per below code and add your code on any event.

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on("click",".yourclass", function() {
            //put here your code
       });
    });
});
```

hope it helps to you!